# Recursive function is not defined inside itself

Tags: python, recursion, nameerror

I'm trying to write a program to solve the [N Queens Puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle). I'm getting the error `name 'FindPosition' is not defined` when the code tries to call `FindPosition(finalArray, startArray)` recursively. How do I properly call the function?

```
class TheQueensAlgoritm():

    def FindPosition(finalArray, startArray):

        if len(startArray)==0:
            print(finalArray)
            return
        else:
            startIndex = 0

            while startIndex <= len(startArray):
                finalIndex = len(finalArray) - 1

                while finalIndex >= 0:                                                        
                    if (not(startArray[startIndex] == finalArray[finalIndex] - finalIndex + startIndex) and not(startArray[startIndex] == finalArray[finalIndex] + finalIndex - startIndex)):
                        finalIndex = finalIndex - 1                    
                    else:
                        break
                    finalArray.append(startArray[startIndex])
                    startArray.remove(finalArray[-1])
                    FindPosition(finalArray, startArray)
                startIndex = startIndex + 1

            startArray.append(finalArray[-1])
            finalArray.remove(startArray[-1])
            FindPosition(finalArray, startArray)        

    startArray = []
    finalArray = []  
    boardSize = input("Type the size of the board = ")
    boardSize = int(boardSize)

    for i in range (0, boardSize):
        startArray.append(i) 

    finalArray.append(startArray[random.randint(0,boardSize-1)])  
    startArray.remove(finalArray[0])                              
    FindPosition(finalArray, startArray)
```

Comment: Why did you make a class?

Comment: I don't know, deleting it solved the issue! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FindPosition` is a method of the class `TheQueensAlgoritm` and does not exist by itself. You need to use:

```
self.FindPosition(finalArray, startArray)
```

Comment: The self parameter is missing as well, no? Otherwise, self is undefined

Comment: Yes, the function def should be `def FindPosition(self, finalArray, startArray):`

Comment: @cricket_007 Note that the name `self` is just a convention. In the OP code `finalArray` is actually used as `self` and the method has only one explicit parameter which is `startArray`, so calls with two parameters will trigger an error.

Comment: @Bakuriu Yes, it's convention. The fact that there will be that error is what I'm getting at

Comment: Downvoted: this will not fix the problem for the reasons outlined in comments.